# I'm trying to use SSHFS to transfer files via SSH to my Raspberry Pi web server, specifically using the GUI

Tags: gnome, ssh, gui, sshfs

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux. I am running 20.04. So as per the question title I am trying to transfer HTML/CSS etc files to my Raspberry Pi where I am running an Apache web server.

I have been searching and following the web for how to do this and have pieced together from multiple sources the following:

I have enabled SSH on Ubuntu and the Pi.
I have installed SSHFS on Ubuntu.

Now I am opening the Files app and on the left hand side clicking on + Other Locations

At the bottom I am entering ssh://192.168.1.20, then press Enter to connect.

I then enter the username and password. And successfully connect. I am presented with the file structure from root.

I have managed to copy files too and from successfully. So I am assuming this is the correct way to achieve what I am trying to achieve. Please correct me if not.

I am having an issue though - once am I connected and presented with the root - if I navigate to another place on MY computer using the same window (using the left hand side), when I go back to the Pi, I am then shown the Home folder on the Pi and can see no way of getting back to the root without disconnecting and reconnecting. This is frustrating and I don't understand why this is the case?

Can anyone help please?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Discover the path you need in Nautilus**

1. Navigate to the pi Home dir.
2. Right-Click on empty space. Select "Properties". Look for the "Parent Folder" field.

   - Example: `ssh://192.168.1.32/home/me`

**Use the path in Nautilus**

3. Click the empty Top Bar at the top of the window.

   - If you start to type, the bar will change into a Search box.
   - If your first character is a slash (/), you can enter file paths (note the little file icon on the left side of the box)
   - DON'T paste. It only works for typing.
   - DON'T use the search icon. While it will open a similar search box, it won't convert into paths.
4. Enter the root folder path: `ssh://192.168.1.32/`

   - Use a dummy slash (/) so the box accepts file paths, then delete the slash, then enter the path

[image: Example Nautilus file path]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've followed your instructions and it works for me. I've also discovered that you can have a config file in .ssh - here I have given the IP a short simple Host Name so I can type that as opposed to the IP etc. Are you aware of a way of making a change somewhere so that upon connecting via SSH it simply defaults to root and doesn't change to the Home folder? Many thanks again.